# Radio buttons js appending only one (edited)

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have added a js code to style the selected input, and it works:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('.img-check').click(function (e) {
      $('.img-check').not(this).removeClass('check').siblings('input').prop('checked', false);
      $(this).addClass('check').siblings('input').prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

The only issue is when I introduce another set of radio buttons, I am only able to select one between the two.

The inputs are still being selected, its the class 'check' can only be one between the two radio buttons.

How do i make the radio buttons independent of each other without having to give it unique identifiers?

(edited)

basically I am using the structure of this snip
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/1e8xr

the problem is when I have two sets of radio buttons, only one is still selected between the two...

Comment: Radio buttons are grouped via their `name` attribute. If you want two separate groups, use two different names for each group.

Comment: yes they are grouped with different name att. the issue is the js code only styling one selected input. the radios work, just not the class

Comment: Styling, what styling? We have no idea what your HTML looks like, so this is basically impossible to answer as of now. Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Most likely you just need to be more specific with how you select the elements to begin with.